# What are the side effects of "ulimit -t unlimited" in ksh93?

Tags: ksh, ulimit

I was bitten by this [ksh93 bug](https://github.com/att/ast/issues/73) (also [here](https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/issues/15)). Here is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) close to my use case:

```
$ cat bug.sh
#!/bin/ksh93

unset a b
c=0

function set_ac { a=1; c=1; }
function set_abc { ( set_ac ; b=1 ) }

set_abc
echo "a=$a b=$b c=$c"

$ ./bug.sh
a=1 b= c=0
```

Hence, although `set_abc` calls `set_ac` in a subshell, the assignment `a=1` propagates to the parent shell. There are a few known [workarounds](https://github.com/att/ast/issues/73#issuecomment-644012380) and I'm leaning towards the one that says to replace `set_abc` above with

```
function set_abc { ( ulimit -t unlimited ; set_ac ; b=1 ) }
```

This seems to work fine. Now I wonder if there is any side effect of `ulimit -t unlimited` other than provoking the subshell to fork (this is the point of the workaround) that can cause me trouble in the future. (FWIW: This is supposed to be ran by a user without root privileges.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest ksh93 release's implementation of non-forking/virtual subshells is chock-full of bugs. A subshell is supposed to be an environment that is copied from, but cleanly separated from the parent shell environment. Forcing the subshell to fork delegates that separation to the kernel, which is very robust. So the only side effects should be that you get (1) sightly slower performance and (2) much fewer bugs.

As for `ulimit` itself, using the `unlimited` parameter should not cause any side effects either because that is the default. The only possibility is that a parent shell environment already limited the CPU time with `ulimit -t`; in that case you don't have permission to set it back to `unlimited` and it prints an error message. However, it still forces the fork. So to be completely safe, you can use `ulimit -t unlimited 2>/dev/null` instead, to suppress any possible error message.

Comment: Just to add that a few of us are actively working on fixing those bugs and many others at: https://github.com/ksh93/ksh – every interested party is invited to contribute. ksh lives!